# Source map does not work

Tags: haxe, source-maps

In chrome, I have enabled source map, and I build my project like this:

```
haxelib run lime build "project.xml" html5 -debug -Dsource-map-content -Dwebgl
```

I've noticed that `project.js.map` is created, and haxe folder in debug folder has all hx files, however in the browser, I can see only the project.js file.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you enabled JS source maps on the Chrome Developer Tools settings?

Comment: Yes, I did, it's already enabled.

Comment: Perhaps the paths inside the map file are wrong, have changed (from the point of view of either haxe or chrome) or aren't accessible to chrome.  Do they make sense?

Comment: So, how do I fix file paths? what should they be? actually I am not at home to investigate..

Comment: I'm not sure how lime does it, but haxe simply refers the map to the original hx absolute path.  But I suspect lime might try something different because you said your debug folder has been filled with hx files...

Comment: @jonasmalacofilho thanks for trying to help, I found that because my javascript file has space character within the name, the mapping was unable to find the map file, so, i just made the name without spaces..